# PostgreSQL database interaction in C#

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, postgresql

I'm working on a project in which I have a PostgreSQL database containing various tables and what not. I have a c# application that needs to be able to enter new data/change existing data/ or retrieve data from the database.

My question is, is there some tool/framework that I should be using to make this interaction easier. Currently, we have written a bunch of database helper functions to make various common operations simple in C#, we've written classes that define what a Column and Table are. We have defined data model classes for all the tables in the database as well as defined table classes corresponding to each data model class.

Basically, we written a lot of code just to be able to interface with the database and I feel like there has to be a simpler way. But maybe not! That's why I'm asking.

I saw some people using the Entity Framework but I'm not familiar with it and don't know if it does what I'm looking for. Also, it seemed like it was geared towards MySql and the free PostgreSql tool for it were a bit hacky.

Comment: It can be as simple as not creating any new classes, and just using the DB classes provided in the .NET framework.  It can be as complicated as creating your own [ORM framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping).  Or it can be anything in between (like using Entity Framework or a third party ORM framework).  Your question is too broad for this site.

Comment: Be aware that your question is not specific to postgresql.  Every database has this issue.  It is sometimes called the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is:  you are probably already doing it the best way with current technologies.

I have tried several ORM solutions and all of them failed to live up to expectations on one level or another.  Entity Framework is starting to get mature, but as you already found, the PostgreSQL adapters are essentially hacks since EF is baked for Microsoft SQL at a low level.  One of the better ones I have used is Telerik's ORM, but it costs $$$$ and is far from perfect (http://www.telerik.com/data-access).

One to look at is this:  https://www.nuget.org/packages/Shaolinq.Postgres.DotConnect/  Note though that is is an early version, I have not used it myself and generally use at your own risk:)

There are some code first and Node.js specific tools out there that are starting to get interesting, but in the end, having some decent reusable data access library and object classes is generally still the best solution for general use.